# how to run terminal scripts to the ios

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, converters

i have terminal script for ffmpeg like : `ffmpeg -i input_file -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline out.mp4`

how can i run something like this in my app

Comment: ios may be based on bsd, but you're highly unlikely to get **ANY** kind of shell access, because that'd make it far too easy to root/subvert the system. plus... even if you do get your app onto the device, how do you think you'll get ffmpeg installed?

Comment: because i am stuck now i tried to open to open avi files in my iphone using 'IFrameExtractor' but it's work without sound and and i can't something open sound file using ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with the native iOS SDK, as that could easily lead to malicious apps on the App Store. If you must do so, try mobile terminal from cydia on a jailbroken iPhone, even then I doubt you would somehow be able to install ffmpeg on iOS without any porting. http://cydia.saurik.com/package/mobileterminal/